# Zipcodes & Distance

Tags: mysql, geolocation, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a list of zipcoded in a MySQL Database together with their Latitude & Longitude data (Column names: ZipCode, Lat, Lon).

Now I have to make a search requests (search for the zipcode) to extract information from a website. When I make this search requests the results include all information within a radius of 50km of the zipcode.

Now, I don't want to make an unnessary high amount of search requests, so I would like to minimize the amount of zipcodes. So I'm looking for a way to filter all zipcodes, so that I have only the zipcodes where the distance between them is >50km.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to to it.
Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: change "between them is >50km" to "between them is <50km" I think that is what you meant.

Comment: @Chris I think >50km is deliberate. We want a set of 50km radius searches which covers all zip codes in as few searches as possible. Therefore we can discard any zip code that's within 50km of one we've already selected, and the ones we keep will be >50km apart.

Comment: The result should be a list of zipcodes where the distance between two zipcodes is >50km.
In the beginning I have a list of e.g. 10.000 zipcodes with a huge amount of zipcodes where the proximity is very small. Afterwards I should have a smaller list of zipcodes (e.g. 2000 zipcodes) with a proximity of >50km between them.

Comment: You might try asking this question of http://gis.stackexchange.com , a new stackoverflow like site for geographic information systems (GIS) questions

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in checking out the following presentation:

- [Geo/Spatial Search with MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) by Alexander Rubin

The author describes how you can use the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) in MySQL to limit your searches to a defined range. He also describes how to avoid a full table scan for such queries, using traditional indexes on the latitude and longitude columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [google geocoding api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) , it allows you to get distances between 2 locations (lat/long, it also allows you to get zip from lat/long). From this you should be able to get the distance between each of your zipcodes and put them into a table, then you can do searches on just these.

Comment: How would you store distances between zipcodes in your table?  What would this distance be between ?  Are you saying have a distance table which has id, id(zipcode1), id(zipcode2), distance and have an entry for every combination of 2 zip codes?

Comment: No, I would have a many to many that relates zips to the other zips that are within 50 miles, or if you prefer a less normalized approach, you could have zipcode1 and 2nd column is a comma list of the zips within 50 miles, if performance is king, this would work. You only need

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see no other way then to iterate all rows on each request and filter them by calculating distance between selected zipcode and others (all of them), based on Lat & Lon.

I am using something similiar...
http://webarto.com/googlemaps
http://webarto.com/izrada-web-stranica/belgrade

PHP function for distance between two LL...

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2){ 
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2; 
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)); 
  $dist = acos($dist); 
  $dist = rad2deg($dist); 
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  return round($miles * 1.609344,3);
}
```

I calculate it this way...

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM geoip WHERE city = '$city'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $ll = explode(",",$row["ll"]);
    $x = distance(44.5428009033,18.6693992615,$ll[0],$ll[1]);
    $road = intval($x+($x/3));

    echo "Distance between ".$row["city"]." and Tuzla is ".$x." kilometers of airline, that's about ".$road." kilometers of road way.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's link deals with selecting all the zip codes within 50km of a given latitude/longitude. Once you can do that, you can build a filtered list of zipcodes like this...

1. Select a zip code at random and add it to the filtered list
2. Delete all zip codes which lie within 50km of the selected zip code
3. Select a new zip code at random from the remaining zip codes, repeat until no more are left.

You know that you're only picking zip codes that are >50km from the ones already picked, and you know that once the original table is empty it must be because all zip codes lie within 50km of at least one of your selected zip codes.

That doesn't guarantee the smallest possible list of zip codes, and the size of the result will depend on the random choices. However, I think that this simple algorithm is likely to be "good enough", and that saving a few searches wouldn't justify the extra effort involved in finding a truly optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been discussed previously [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778866/eliminate-subquery-for-average-numeric-value) with various solutions

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I used this solution to find the answer. Not sure if you are using java or some other language but the logic can be used in any programming language
[Geo Location API and finding user within a radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977322/geo-location-api-and-finding-user-within-a-radius/7933230#7933230)