# Avoiding a Full Table Scan in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I avoid a full table scan on mysql?

Comment: This is the third time you've asked this question in a different guise. Why don't you just read the MySQL Reference Manual section about query optimisation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, by making sure you have a usable index on fields that appear in `WHERE`, `JOIN` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: .. and by having a primary key on the table.

Comment: @XSaint32 you don't need a primary key to avoid FTS.

Comment: @gumpi: The problem is that `getDistance()` function. You may want to check out the presentation I linked to in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521503/zipcodes-distance/3521564#3521564

Comment: It makes lots of sense, thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Index your data.

Write queries that use those indexes.

Anything more than that we need specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that sometimes you just can not rid of a full table scan, i.e. When you need all the rows from your table... or when the cost of scanning the index is gt the cost of scanning the full table.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LIMIT clause when you know how many rows you are expecting to return, for example if you are looking for a record with a known ID field that is unique, limit your select to 1, that way mysql will stop searching after it finds the first record.  The same goes for updates and deletes.

```
SELECT * FROM `yourTable` WHERE `idField` = 123 LIMIT 1
```