# Geo Location API and finding user within a radius

Tags: java, geolocation

I have a Java application and I would like to find out the location of a visitor. The API would give me a the zip code of visitor and then based on that zip code, I will find fire a query and get users in my application within 25/50 mile radius.
Alternatively visitor can type in the zip code of their interest and application should return users withing x mile of radius.
For the users who are registered in the system, we have only their zip code.
I have looked around some options but not found the exact solution. I do not want to download the database of zip code and maintain them.
I do not think Google API support this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find any service which offers API . After much research i found that you will have to download zip codes along with their latitude and longitude positions into a table. Then
calculate co ordinates within the radius you want to search.
This is the website which helped me a lot. 
http://www.dougv.com/2009/03/27/getting-all-zip-codes-in-a-given-radius-from-a-known-point-zip-code-via-php-and-mysql/

Here is the calculation in java if you really if you do not want to work with php

//this you will get by querying the database against the zip code
        Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(zipCode.getLatitude());
        Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(zipCode.getLongitude());

```
    Double latN =Math.asin(
            Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latitude)) * Math.cos(distance/radius) + 
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)) * Math.sin(distance/radius) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(0)));


    Double latS =Math.asin(
            Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latitude)) * Math.cos(distance/radius) + 
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)) * Math.sin(distance/radius) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(180)));


    Double longE = Math.toRadians(longitude) + 
                    Math.atan2(
                            Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) * Math.sin(distance/radius)* Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)) 
            , Math.cos(Math.toRadians(distance/radius)) - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latitude))* Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latN)) );

    Double longW = Math.toRadians(longitude) + 
    Math.atan2(
                    Math.sin(Math.toRadians(270)) * Math.sin(distance/radius)* Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)) 
                , Math.cos(Math.toRadians(distance/radius)) - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latitude))* Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latN)) );

    System.out.println("Latutude N "+Math.toDegrees(latN) +" Latitide S "+Math.toDegrees(latS) +">>> Longitude E "+Math.toDegrees(longE) +" Longitude W "+Math.toDegrees(longW));
```

Comment: To read up more on the algorithm for calculating distance (and accounting for an approximation of curvature of the earth) read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how accurate it is, but have you looked at [IPinfoDB](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php)? They'll return XML and JSON results but you'll need to register for an API key. It doesn't provide anything for a radius though, but for nearby zipcodes, you can use something like this: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearbyPostalCodes

Comment: Thanks Jon. I will check out the details

Comment: Ipinfodb gives me the zip code of the visitor. It does not gives radius. geonames gives the radius but is not complete. Still looking for options to get the data within a radius