# Geo Database - find points

Tags: java

If you have a geo database which specifies points on the map, how will you find the points which will fall within four given points? How will you implement an algorithm which clubs points which are next to each other into circles which are 1 miles in radius?

Comment: Your 'Hows' apart. What have you tried so far?

Comment: a) Polygon.contains(point); b) Is to difficult for you

Comment: This is a relatively challenging thing to do efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it really helps to just draw it out.

```
| a
|     b
|   x     
|d     c
|---------
```

so every point will have two coordinates (x,y). A simple way to check if a point is within 4 points is by checking their coordinates.

For the sake of simplicity assume that you know that the x-coordinate of a and d is less than the x-coordinate of b and c, and that the y-coordinate of a and b is greater than the y-coordinate of d and c. Then you can assume that if x is within those four points, then:

```
The x coordinate of x (using x(x) to make it shorter) can be described by
x(x)>=a(x) 
and x(x)>=d(x) 
and x(x)<=b(x) 
and x(x)<=c(x)
```

Similar logic should work for the y coordinate. Please note though, there are much more efficient ways of doing this, I was just trying to illustrate the issue to hopefully make it more clear.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977322/geo-location-api-and-finding-user-within-a-radius) might help as well and offers a more efficient way to look at the issue.